# Symfony - sfGuardUser - How to log group or permissions changes?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, sfguard

I log changes for objects in my application within the processForm function by checking for
differences in the object before and after its been saved.   I persist that to a log table in my database.

For the sfGuardUser backend, I use the generated admin,
which automatically saves changes made to the embedded groups
or permissions.

I'd like to log those changes - but where can I add my log process?

Comment: are you using doctrine or propel?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the best place to handle such change is in the model instead of in the processForm. This is the perfect job of a behavior.

There is a behavior called [versionable](http://www.propelorm.org/behaviors/versionable) which do exactly what you did: historize each change on a model and you just have to define it in your schema.yml:

```
BlogPost:
  _propel_behaviors:
    versionable:
      log_created_at: true
      log_created_by: true
      log_comment: true
  columns:
    title: string(255)
    body: clob
```

So maybe you can get inspiration from [this behavior](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/tree/master/generator/lib/behavior/versionable) to create your own. And then you just to modify the [schema.yml](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/config/schema.yml) of sfGuard, like:

```
sfGuardGroupPermission:
  _attributes:    { phpName: sfGuardGroupPermission }
  _propel_behaviors:
    versionable: { log_created_at: true, log_created_by: true, log_comment: true }
```

**Edit:**
Switched to Propel.